# Normal Outbound Email Relay Vs Smart Host Outbound Email Relay

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

What is the Difference b/w Sending Outbound Emails normally via Send Connectors and Sending Outbound Emails via Smarthost in MS Exchange 2013.

Answer (score 1):

They are going out via different routes. A smart host would be a host external to your network - either used because your Exchange server cannot see the internet, or there is an issue with the internet connection which means remote servers are rejecting the email.

Comment: Hi Sembee, Thanks for the answer. I wanted to know that when I configure send connector via MX record then in this case my email will route outbound, and when i configure send connector via smart host in this case also my Emails will route outbound. In both cases email will go to the internet,but What is the main difference in both of them? Is there are chances of SPAM emails if i configured send connector via MX record rather than Smart host.

Comment: My answer answers your question - the difference is the emails go to the internet via different routes. As for whether your emails will be flagged as spam or not that isn't possible to answer. In some cases a smart host can make things worse because the server is used by many others, but it can also be better. Likewise for direct delivery. If you were concerned about the messages being flagged as spam via the different methods then you should have asked that instead.

Answer (score 1):

A Send Connector can be configured to deliver email via the MX record of the destination domain (DNS MX record lookup) or via a smarthost (SMTP relay).

Comment: Hi joeqwerty, Thanks for the answer. I wanted to know that when I configure send connector via MX record then in this case my email will route outbound, and when i configure send connector via smart host in this case also my Emails will route outbound. In both cases email will go to the internet,but What is the main difference in both of them? Is there are chances of SPAM emails if i configured send connector via MX record rather than Smart host.
Kindly elaborate this, I have a confusion in this,